# CSS layout changes with font-style

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML markup. In most browsers that I have tested, the second list is displayed differently (each list item is indented).

The only difference between the two lists relates to the CSS font-style property, which I would not expect to change the list layout. Is there a explanation for this behavior?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {font-family: sans-serif}
            span {float: left}
            ul.bad span {font-style: italic}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="bad">
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
            <li><span>foo</span></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser?  How is the layout differing?  I see no difference in Firefox with the code provided save for the italicized text.

Comment: Not sure what's causing it, but removing the `span {float:left}` would fix the indentation issue.

Comment: @Jrod - I'm seeing the bottom list staggered (each successive foo farther right) in FF 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The span `span` with the straight text becomes **18 pixels** in height, while the *italic* text forces the `span` to **19 pixels**.

This causes a slightly different behaviour when using `float: left`.

```
      span // <-- height: 18px;
 .bad span // <-- height: 19px;
```

a **quick fix** would be to set the `line height` property equal  for both span types:

```
  span {float:left; line-height:15px;}
```

not regarding the intentions of your code ;)

Comment: just tried that myself, and setting the line-height to 15px works; setting it to a larger value (say, 35px) causes the staggering in both lists.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the answer. Looks like I have a bit of reading ahead of me to understand _why_ this is the case. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the sans-serif font selected by the browser has different italic (or no italics). Try selecting a specific font like verdana instead and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Layout will depend on real fonts used for "sans-serif" substitution. 
So you will need to chose proper font name.

I do not see any differences in all major browsers on Windows (7), see: http://jsfiddle.net/uTjSd/ 
It appears as "sans-serif" is resolved to "Arial" in all of them.